# Nativescript, On Android a element disappear when using scrollview and Repeater

Tags: android, ios, repeater, nativescript, android-scrollview

When i press the gridlayout tap="{{ ShowSetting }}", it fires a function that make the two buttons accept and decline visible. SettingHide = "visible". When this happens, item1 and item2 disappear!?
If i remove the scrollview the problem is gone, and on IOS it works.

I need help, tried bunch of stuff like ListView and same problem.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="PageLoaded">
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Main-Page.css"?>

<ScrollView> 
      <StackLayout>  

      <Repeater items="{{ Items }}">
          <Repeater.itemTemplate>

<GridLayout columns="*,auto, *" rows="auto,auto" tap="{{ ShowSetting }}">

 <Label text="{{ item1}}" row="0" col="0"></Label>

 <Label text="{{ item2 }}" row="0" col="2"></Label>

 <Button text="Accept" row="3" col="0" colSpan="2" visibility="{{SettingHide }}"></Button>

<Button text="Decline" row="3" col="2" colSpan="2" visibility="{{SettingHide }}"></Button>

</GridLayout>

          </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
  <StackLayout>
 <ScrollView> 
</Page>
```

Comment: I would guess you need to make sure the value for `settingHide` = `visible` or `collapsed`.     Not a boolean value...

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. The variable is set to visible and collapsed, not true or false. It is working on iOS perfect. But on Android it collapses and make it visible the right element, but hides other elements to that is above the element i collapse or set visible. Dosent matter if the variable is set to visible or collapse, the element above hides anyway. And this only happens if i use scrollview element. If i remove it, the problem is gone.

Comment: Are you sure of the heights of the elements?

Comment: seeing the same thing all these years later X_X so strange